# python post request bitso api withdrawal

Tags: python, json, post, request, bitcoin

Im trying to do a post request on the bitso Api using python to perform a debit card withdrawal. the api is telling me "Body parameters should be JSON encoded and should be exactly the same as the JSON payload used to construct the signature." the body parameters are.  amount , recipient_given_names ,recipient_family_names, card_number, bank_code, i just want to know how i can add the body parameters to the post request of the following code.

```
    bitso_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'

    bitso_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

    nonce =  str(int(round(time.time() * 10000)))

    http_method = "POST"

    request_path = "/v3/balance/"

    json_payload = ""

  # Create signature

    message = nonce+http_method+request_path+json_payload

    signature = hmac.new(bitso_secret.encode('utf-8'),

                                        message.encode('utf-8'),

                                        hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # Build the auth header

    auth_header = 'Bitso %s:%s:%s' % (bitso_key, nonce, signature)



    # Send request

    bitso_withdrawal = requests.post("https://api.bitso.com/v3/debit_card_withdrawal/",headers={"Authorization": auth_header})
```

Comment: Why you are not passing the message in requests.post? `requests.post(url, data, headers)`. Than I do not understand why you have `http_method = get`?

Comment: Im Still a noob but i changed  http_method = "POST" i entered in the body the data as a dictionary and as json.dumps(data) and am still not able to get the correct response from the api. im getting closer i feel so thank you for the help

Comment: You should edit your question with the new code so will be simpler find the answer  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi man I highly recommend you to use the API wrapper Bitso provides, it already has the method you want to use.

Those wrappers are available for python and java

https://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py

https://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-java

Here is a basic program:

```
import time
import hmac
import hashlib
import requests
import json
import random
import sys

def main(argv):
    bitso_url = "https://api.bitso.com"
    bitso_key = "<KEY>"
    bitso_secret = "<SECRET>"

    nonce = str(int(round(time.time())) * 100000 * 2)

    http_method = "POST"
    request_path = "/api/v3/<POST_ENDPOINT>" 

    payload = {}
    #Add required keys of the parameters to the json
    #As follows
    #payload["<needed key>"] = <key value>

    json_payload = json.dumps(payload)

    # Create signature
    message = nonce + http_method + request_path + json_payload
    signature = hmac.new(bitso_secret.encode('utf-8'),
                        message.encode('utf-8'),
                        hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # Build the auth header
    auth_header = 'Bitso %s:%s:%s' % (bitso_key, nonce, signature)

    # Send request
    response = requests.post(bitso_url+request_path,
        headers = {"Authorization" : auth_header},
        json = payload)

    print(response.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main(sys.argv[1:])
```